Place external object data on page layout
I have an external data source that I've set up a connector for.
The external data source creates a few external objects, let's call the external object 'House'. This House object has fields, NumberOfBedrooms and NumberOfWindows.
Now, let's say on an existing object I want to add an external lookup to this new Remote Object.
So perhaps I update the Case object to always have a House using the external Lookup field type.
When viewing a Case, I'd like to be able to show data from the associated House on the Case Layout. So when I view a case, I want to see NumberOfBedrooms and NumberOfWindows from the external object specified in the external lookup field.
In the lightning builder I can drag on the field for the House object and it provides a link to the external object, but, what I really want is to show the data from the external lookup on the Case page layout.
Is there a way to do that?

rather than the Case layout, how about another component on the Lightning record page that is a related record component?

@cropredy I’m fairly new to this, but does the related record component have the capability to show the data from the related records , or does it just show links?

it can show data; fields shown are defined by a quick action layout. There are also cross-object fields on dynamic forms though these are read-only
